# Django and floatformat tag

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to modify / change the way the [floatformat](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#floatformat) works.

By default it changes the input decimal as such:

```
{{ 1.00|floatformat }} -> 1
{{ 1.50|floatformat }} -> 1.5
{{ 1.53|floatformat }} -> 1.53
```

I want to change this abit as such: If there is a floating part, it should keep the first 2 floating digits. If no floating (which means .00) it should simply cut out the floating part. IE:

```
{{ 1.00|floatformat }} -> 1
{{ 1.50|floatformat }} -> 1.50
{{ 1.53|floatformat }} -> 1.53
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Doesn't using a parameter of -2, as described in the docs you link to, do what you want?

```
{{ 1.00|floatformat:-2 }}
```

See Django Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#floatformat

Comment: Is there any way to force integers to have .00 at the end?? Like {{ 1|floatformat:-2 }} should be 1.00 instead of 1?

Comment: @KarthikRP - `{{ 1|floatformat:2 }}` outputs "1.00" (note the 2nd arg is positive).